# Vim insert mode: unambiguous key binding that always works as expected?

Tags: vim, insert, editor, mode

**Background:**

Sometimes when editing in vim it is possible to have extra characters in a file that the user did not expect to be there because he was in "insert mode" when in a hurry and rushing to get something finished.

Fortunately, even if the user is rushing, pressing ESC a couple of times is *always* sufficient to get them out of insert mode and into normal mode, with no surprises.

**Question:**

Is there a key binding that works the same way for insert mode? Pressing "i" can get you into insert mode, but if you press it multiple times, you will start inserting the letter "i" into the file.

**Goal:**

The goal is to have some key binding for getting back into insert mode that the user can even press multiple times with eyes closed, and still not worry about "surprises" of unexpected characters being put into the file.

Comment: I can't think of any easy combination per se, but it's trivial to make bindings that enter insert mode, but do nothing IN insert mode.

Comment: have you looked at [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Avoid_the_escape_key#Toggling_insert_mode)

Comment: Tom Ingram: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately, that suggestion shows how to *toggle* insert mode (turn it on and off) ... the goal for this particular question is to find a way to turn it on and know it is on, without inserting any characters in the buffer, even if you hit the keybinding multiple times in succession.

Comment: if you do not wish to toggle then change `inoremap <F12> <Esc>` to 
`inoremap <F12> <nop>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<C-o>i` should do the trick. `<C-o>` gets you temporarily to normal mode, but for only one command, if that command is "go to insert mode" than well, you simply return there.

---

Edit: I could reproduce your error message now, and it seems the easiest thing to do is this:

```
:nmap <C-i> i
:imap <C-i> <C-o>i
```

If do not map `<C-i>` in insert mode, but in normal mode only, then repeatedly hitting `<C-i>` will be idempotent.

Thanks to Benoit for mentioning that `<C-i>` inserts a tab in insert mode.

Comment: CTRL-O has a different meaning also in normal mode. I wouldn't advise that, and therefore the -1.

Comment: @Benoit: Yes, you are right. See my edit, that should do the trick.

Comment: in insert mode, CTRL-I inserts a tab character.

Comment: @bitmask Your mapping forbids to use `<Tab>` (which is a common choice for completion in insert mode and also useful in normal mode): because `<C-i>` is not inserting a tab character, it is *itself* a tab character. And, by the way, you forgot `nore`.

Comment: @ZyX: Well, the choice where to which combination/key to map is obviously something the user has to decide, so if you rely on the `<Tab>` feature, do not use `<C-i>` but something else.

Answer (score 4):

You should do a mapping that behaves differently in the distinct modes:

```
:inoremap <F1> <NOP>
:nnoremap <F1> i
:vnoremap <F1> <esc>i
:cnoremap <F1> <C-C>i
:onoremap <F1> <esc>i
```

Hitting F1 will go to insert mode then.

You can also toggle the `'insertmode'` setting (`:set insertmode`): in this mode, the Insert mode is the default mode (to which you switch with Escape, and you go to normal mode with CTRL-L.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This helps in situations where the user has the ability to change vimrc ... plain-vanilla vim solutions are good too though, (where the user may not have the ability or willingness to change vimrc).

Answer (score 2):

The answer given by bitmask works, but it apparently has the side-effect of producing the error message:

E37: No write since last change (add ! to override)

Unless you have configured your vimrc to turn that message off.

But another alternative that seems to work without producing error messages:

```
CTRL-C i
```

Which seems to work on standard vim.